# not able to open the eclipse 2012-12

Tags: eclipse, windows-11

I am not able to open the eclipse by clicking on `eclipse.exe` file.

**version details are :**

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639
```

**eclipse.ini**

```
-clean
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.11/bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.400.v20211117-0650
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.1.v20211116-1657/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1064m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

> did I miss anything in the .ini file?

Comment: You don't need that -clean or the first -vm and Java 11. There is already a -vm later in the ini using the built in Java 17 that comes with Eclipse - use that. You should not need to change anything in the eclipse.ini for a fresh install.

Comment: The [first `-vm` is incorrect at this position](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) and not needed since your Eclipse includes a Java to run Eclipse. Configure the JDKs/JREs you like to use in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_ and do not edit the `eclipse.ini` for that.